# Apache druid database design

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema, druid

I have heard lot of druid aggregation capabilities.

Can someone share any blog/material as to how a druid data base model looks like ,probably with a UML diagram.

I am currently exploring druids quick aggregation capabilities.

Also it would be highly appreciated if you can share a active online forum for druid discussion.

Thanks

Comment: Active online forum is the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/druid-user

Comment: @leventov Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below blog clarified almost all of the schema design doubts and concerns i had

[offcial druid forum in google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-development/O42vKSXMI-g)

I will add other such druid beginner blogs as and when i find